# How to push related data to an array using angular or native javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

recieving event from socket there are more attributes in the data what we need , so i only need to key value that are defined in interface object, so when we recieve data how to push only related data to an array ?

app.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
       this.socket.on('newMessage', (event) => {
                 console.log('Datasource', event);
                  this.dataSource.data.push(event);
                   this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]
                  console.log("DATASOURCEINIT",this.dataSource.filteredData);
               });;
        });
    }

export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

event data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59cbd128b41475991bb6624f"),
    "ticketState" : "Closed",
    "rootCauseCode" : 50,
    "escalationDeadline" : 0,
    "totalImpactedCustomers" : 0,,
    "ebmIndicator" : 0,
    "adjustedTimeToRestore" : 30,
    "keyItemAffected" : "LSVOIP.voip_scripts-6-1:1",
    "rootCause" : "Other",
    "ticketNum" : "0000002324638628",
    "agentID" : "dd808a",
    "assetID" : "5065295027006",
    "ticketRole" : "Main",
    "riskIndex" : "H",
    "eventType" : "UPDATE-Customer Log",
    "avgCreditAmt" : "110.00",
    "adjustedTimeToRepair" : 30,
    "ISOCurrencyCode" : "USD",
    "ticketPriority" : "6",
    "functionalArea" : "GLOBAL_AM",
    "reportedCustomerImpact" : 0,
    "assetPriority" : "Normal",
    "rootTicketId" : "000000234638628",
    "workQueue" : "VOIP_RULES",
    "creditAmt" : "120.00",
    "nodeName" : "LSVOIP_15065295",
    "ticketStateID" : "3014",
    "activeOrg" : "MO-BGTN-APPL",
    "restoreDuration" : "0",
    "severity" : "5 - Normal",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "1506529546",
    "riskValue" : 1,
    "ticketOpened" : 1506529510,

}
```

Need Just these key pairs

```
{
        ticketNum: number;
        ticketOpened: number;
        eventType: string;
        riskIndex: string;
        riskValue: number;
        severity: string;
        lastModifiedDate: number;
        assetID: string;
    }
```

Comment: Show us what the data is and what you need from it.

Comment: @yBrodsky added  event and what i need from it

Comment: Do you need the value types converted or can you take them as they were? For example you say `ticketNum: number` and yet in the original object it is a string. Can it stay a string (which includes the leading `0`s. Or do you want it as a number? Which will remove the leading `0`s. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will take the original values as they are and not attempt to convert them to a different type. If you have to have the data converted then I would need to change the code.

```js
    var obj = {
      "_id" : "59cbd128b41475991bb6624f",
      "ticketState" : "Closed",
      "rootCauseCode" : 50,
      "escalationDeadline" : 0,
      "totalImpactedCustomers" : 0,
      "ebmIndicator" : 0,
      "adjustedTimeToRestore" : 30,
      "keyItemAffected" : "LSVOIP.voip_scripts-6-1:1",
      "rootCause" : "Other",
      "ticketNum" : "0000002324638628",
      "agentID" : "dd808a",
      "assetID" : "5065295027006",
      "ticketRole" : "Main",
      "riskIndex" : "H",
      "eventType" : "UPDATE-Customer Log",
      "avgCreditAmt" : "110.00",
      "adjustedTimeToRepair" : 30,
      "ISOCurrencyCode" : "USD",
      "ticketPriority" : "6",
      "functionalArea" : "GLOBAL_AM",
      "reportedCustomerImpact" : 0,
      "assetPriority" : "Normal",
      "rootTicketId" : "000000234638628",
      "workQueue" : "VOIP_RULES",
      "creditAmt" : "120.00",
      "nodeName" : "LSVOIP_15065295",
      "ticketStateID" : "3014",
      "activeOrg" : "MO-BGTN-APPL",
      "restoreDuration" : "0",
      "severity" : "5 - Normal",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "1506529546",
      "riskValue" : 1,
      "ticketOpened" : 1506529510,
    }

    function trimObj(obj) {
      var neededKeys = ["ticketNum", "ticketOpened", "eventType", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "severity", "lastModifiedDate", "assetID"];
      var newObj = {};
      neededKeys.forEach(
        function (key) {
          newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
      );
      return newObj;
    }

    var a = trimObj(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a,0,2));
```